# FXCollections in over Android

Tags: android, gradle, openfx

I want to use FXCollections (ListProperty) over Android Studio.

I implemented the needed dependency like this:
`implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: '16-ea+7`

but I still am not able to use them.

Does anyone have any ideas on why?
Are you not able to use JavaFx dependencies in Android in general?
Are there any alternatives which provide the same Functions?

Comment: There's already a [ObservableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList) in android.

Comment: ah, didn't know, thx